# Double quotes when concatenating a string with a vector in Clojure

Tags: string, vector, clojure

In Clojure, the code `(println ["foo" "bar"])` prints the following:

```
[foo bar]
```

While the code `(println (str "items: " ["foo" "bar"]))` prints the following:

```
items: ["foo" "bar"]
```

Notice the double quotes around each item in the vector. How can I avoid this? I need a function that concatenates a string with the string representation of a vector, producing this output:

```
items: [foo bar]
```

How can I do this in Clojure?

Comment: Hi Otavio, I've revised my answer - I hope that it works for you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, you don't really need the string concatenation call to `str` because `println` can take multiple arguments. The following works nicely under Clojure 1.3.0:

```
user=> (println "items: " ["foo" "bar"])
items:  [foo bar]
nil
```

**Edit**

I've re-read the question, and I've realised that Otavio was not only intending to print using the example to illustrate his problem with printing from `str`, but also that he does intend to pass concatenated strings to println.

Would suggest the following instead:

```
(println
  (binding [*print-readably* nil]
    (str "items: " ["foo" "bar"])))
```

Output:

```
items: [foo bar]
nil
```

**References**

Docs from the Clojure website under: [Other Useful Functions and Macros](http://clojure.org/other_functions)":

"... `*print-readably*` (which defaults to true) bound to nil, which causes strings to print without surrounding quotes or any escape character encoding, and characters to print without the leading '\', or any escape character encoding. "

Comment: the ["foo" "bar"] vector is converted in a string "[\"foo\" \"bar\"]" when you use the str function

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
user=> (require 'clojure.string)        
nil
user=> (clojure.string/join " " ["foo" "bar"])
"foo bar"
user=> (str "[" (clojure.string/join " " ["foo" "bar"]) "]")
"[foo bar]"
```